# Issues with LogCat

Tags: android, logcat

I was trying to make my first application, and I made 2 pages (LogoActivity (main one) and screen_2). I did not have any problems except with LogCat. I have no idea of what that is. If you can tell something about, I am be pleased to learn :).
This is the log file I got from Eclipse.

```
05-15 21:04:04.981: D/AndroidRuntime(382): Shutting down VM
05-15 21:04:04.981: W/dalvikvm(382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.eyestudios.logo/eu.eyestudios.logo.LogoActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)    
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at eu.eyestudios.logo.LogoActivity.onCreate(LogoActivity.java:14)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Can you post your onCreate function from LogoActivity

Answer (score 1):

These lines

> 05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
>
> 05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at eu.eyestudios.logo.LogoActivity.onCreate(LogoActivity.java:14)

tell you that you are trying to do a cast of an invalid type. Check the code around `LogoActivity.java:14` to figure what's wrong with your cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem is in the imagebutton:

05-15 21:04:05.001: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton

I think you have not find image button by findviewbyid or you are taking wrong id for image button.like (ImageButton)findViewById(R.Id.***imagebutton**)..Check this id matches with image button id in xml.
```